# Why are my bootstrap container columns not staying divided into 4 equal parts?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I've been trying to divide a section from my project into 4 equal parts using the bootstrap col attribute but was unsuccessful in doing it. When executed, there is always the last container which breaks and goes underneath the other 3 making the code look very unpleasant.
**index.html**

```
    <section id="technical_stack">
        <h1 class="section_header">Technical Skills</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 m-2 p-2 skills_tiles">
                    Programming Languages<br>
                    <span class="skills">                        
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 m-2 p-2 skills_tiles">
                    Webdev & Frameworks<br>
                    <span class="skills">                        
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 m-2 p-2 skills_tiles">
                    Databases & Other<br>
                    <span class="skills">                        
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 m-2 p-2 skills_tiles">
                    In development<br>
                    <span class="skills">                        
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-film"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**styles.css**

```
.skills_tiles {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: grid;
    background-color: white;
    color: #212529;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 42px 22px;
    cursor: crosshair;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.skills_tiles:hover {
    background: #212529;
    color: white;
}
```

[image: problem]
As can be seen in the image, one of the columns goes below which destroys the purpose of using the columns and I'm confused to why it's doing this.

Want my code to distribute the columns to 4 equal parts with a nice margin.

Comment: It's _because_ you added the margin. `col-md-3` applies a width of 25%, and four times 25% _plus_ additional margins, will result in an overall width _greater_ than 100%. Use an additional wrapper element inside your columns. The columns have padding by default already, so that will get you the _inner_ wrappers separated from each other.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The margin makes so much sense. I figured out that the problem could be easily fixed with a div where you can add grid layouts within the column containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use column, **margins are not supported**, so remove **m-2**. That means 4 columns will appear in one line. And if you need more space, use **padding**.